# Is there a way to get the page url a form was submitted from without to hide it (url) to the form?

Tags: laravel

I have different pages where users can add comments. I want to save the url of the page where the comment was made so that I can see it afterwards. Is this possible without hiding the the current url to the comment form? For example has the request() such a property? Or is hiding the url to the form the only way for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is a global helper for that

```
url()->previous();
url()->current();
url()->full();
```

If you prefer to use `$request`:

```
$request->url();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#urls

Comment: that was quick. I totally forgot those.